# Set image view underneath the navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar

In my `UIViewController` I have `UIImageView` that takes up the full size of the controller (screen) and serves as a background. On top of UIImageView I have a `UITableView` with a clear background. I set the navigation bar to translucent like this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

`UIImageView` is underneath the navigation bar as I want it to be. Unfortunately the same happens to `UITableView`. I want to put `UITableView` at the bottom of navigation bar, leaving `UIImageView` underneath. If I set:

```
[self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeBottom]
```

then `UITableView` is at the bottom of the navigation bar, but the same happens also to `UIImageView`. What would be the easiest solution to leave `UIImageView` underneath the navigation bar and push down the `UITableView` at the bottom of the navigation bar?

Comment: Why can't you simply set origin for tableView like: `frame.origin.y = 64; tableView.frame = frame;` ?

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout? If so, just add some constraints for the UIImageView and UITableView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default in iOS 7 the content extends to the top and bottom of the screen, underneath any navigation bars, tool bars, or tab bars. If you were to set the *frame* of the table view to be start after the navigation bar, the content of the table view would not scroll beneath the navigation bar providing the nice blur effect.

What you'll probably want to do instead, is keep the y origin of your table view at 0, underneath the navigation bar, and set the content inset so the content starts after the navigation bar.

This is pretty simple. If you're using auto layout the top layout guide of the view controller will recognise the height of the status bar and navigation bar so you don't need to calculate this yourself. The bottom of the navigation bar should end at 66.

```
//Using Auto Layout
CGFloat navigationBarHeight = self.topLayoutGuide.length;

//Not using Auto Layout
UINavigationBar *nav = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
CGFloat navigationBarHeight = nav.frame.origin.y + nav.frame.size.height;

myTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(navigationBarHeight, 0, 0, 0)
```

And of course if you actually do want the frame to start after the navigation bar the height above stays the same, you just need to manually set the frame of the table view.

```
CGRect tableViewFrame = self.view.bounds;
tableViewFrame.origin = CGPointMake(tableViewFrame.origin.x, navigationBarHeight);
tableViewFrame.size = CGSizeMake(tableViewFrame.size.width, tableViewFrame.size.height - navigationBarHeight*2);
myTableView.frame = tableViewFrame;
```

EDIT: Ah, almost forgot. You'll also want to change the scrollIndicatorInsets to match the contentInset, so your scroll bars don't move offscreen.

```
myTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = myTableView.contentInset;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Changing table frame is not a solution for me, because then when table view content will be scrolling it won’t be underneath the the translucent navigation bar. Though navigation bar will pick up nearest cell and try to draw some bit of it simulating that the content is underneath (not the same when table view frame takes full screen). Changing contentInset works perfectly, but you also need to change scrollIndicatorInsets to the same edge insets as contentInset. Otherwise scroller will be underneath the navigation bar. If you update your answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I forgot to mention that. Updated!